# R-package for OPC UA

Tags: r, package, shinydashboard, opc-ua

I would like to know if someone works on a package for **R** using the OPC-UA communication standard.
I found no R-package on CRAN and also on GitHub.

My idea is to to some real-time analysis of data send by a OPC-UA server.

There are some python packages but I don´t know if R is the appropriate language for this network protocol.

In my opinion **R** would be great to visualize data and analyze them.

Answer (score 5):

There is no native OPC UA client for R; however, you can get OPC data into your R application in a variety of ways.

- Use a commercial or write an OPC UA Client to log data into an SQL database and get it from there using R.

  - https://integrationobjects.com/sioth-opc/sioth-opc-data-archiving/opc-client-for-microsoft-sql-server/
  - https://www.striim.com/integrations/opc-ua-microsoft-sql-server/
  - https://openautomationsoftware.com/knowledge-base/log-opc-ua-data-database/
- Use a commercial or write an OPC UA Client to provide a REST interface and get it from there using R.

  - https://openautomationsoftware.com/knowledge-base/how-to-access-opcua-data-rest-api/
  - https://products.softwaretoolbox.com/opc-router/visual-workflow-opc-iiot-sap-database-integration-software
- Use a commercial or write an OPC UA Client to write data to a .txt or .csv file and get it from there using R.

  - https://openautomationsoftware.com/knowledge-base/log-opc-ua-csv-excel/
  - https://integrationobjects.com/sioth-opc/sioth-opc-data-archiving/opc-logger-for-csv/
  - https://opcexpert.com/opc-to-excel/
- Write an OPC UA Client in .NET and call it from your R application.

  - [Calling .NET/C# from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410528/calling-net-c-from-r)
  - [Is it possible call a COM object from within R, if the COM object is exposed from a .NET assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862861/is-it-possible-call-a-com-object-from-within-r-if-the-com-object-is-exposed-fro)
  - [Call R (programming language) from .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025340/call-r-programming-language-from-net)
- Write an OPC UA Client in Go and call it from your R application.

  - https://github.com/gopcua/opcua
  - https://purrple.cat/blog/2017/06/09/go-packages-in-r-packages/
- Same can be done with Python, C, etc.

Personally, I think it would be the easiest to use a database.  OPC Foundation provides a .NET Core [stack](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard) where you can add your own R driver.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know the possibility to insert other languages in R-packages. I didn´t thought the possibility to store the data in databases, great idea.

But why does it give no "native" R-package? Is it the possibility not to go that deep into the network communication?

Comment: OPC is usually used in industrial applications to communicate between PLCs and SCADA applications where PLCs could be from different manufacturers with different (and proprietary) communications protocols and the SCADA market has been dominated by a few major players.  I guess there has not been much demand for statistics outside of what a SCADA system can provide.  In my experience, most OPC software is written in C/C++, with .NET/Java only becoming popular in the last few years.